# Program crashes when I try to change my selected item from listview

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

So, I have a listview and a some items in it. I keep a reference of the selected item in a variable, but if I change my selected item then the program crashes.

```
   private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var prod = (Produs)lvProduse.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
            tb1.Text = prod.Denumire;
            tb2.Text = prod.Pret.ToString();
            tb3.Text = prod.Cantitate.ToString();

        }
```

I guess here is my problem **(Produs)lvProduse.SelectedItems[0].Tag;**. With the first Item I select the program works fine, but if I try to change my selection then I get the System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unhandled exception in the event handler.

Normally, an unhandled exception would cause the debugger to break and tell you what's wrong. But the `ListView.SelectedIndexChanged` event has a bug where your program will just crash outright.

The exception is because when you select a *different* item, you get 2 events:

First, you get an event that notifies you that NO item is selected

Then, you get an event that notifies you that the new item is selected.

In the first event, when NO item is selected, the `lvProduse.SelectedItems` list will be empty. Therefore, accessing element 0 will throw.

You have to check whether an item is selected at all by checking `lvProduse.SelectedItems.Any()` (or perhaps `lvProduse.SelectedItems.Count != 0`, I'm not sure right now if that list supports LINQ) for example.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I inserted   if (lvProduse.SelectedItems.Count == 0) { return;}  and it works. Thank you very much.